# I want to handle the voltage and current spikes from inductive load of 220V AC ceiling fan

Tags: power, ac, dc, triac, dimmer

I am trying to regulate speed of 220V ceiling fan from Arduino but unable to handle the reverse voltage and current though I am applying the flyback diode across inductive load.[image: this is the circuit i have been testing, the circuit with resistive load is working fine in dimming but the inductive one is not working.]

Answer (score 0):

A freewheel diode will end in tears because your circuit is AC .The accepted approach is to place a RC snubber across the noisey triac .